# How to set two values for windowSoftInputMode?

Tags: android

Is it possible yo set two values for `windowSoftInputMode` to be `adjustResize` and `adjustPan`

Comment: Yes, just logical OR them together

Comment: only one affects the UI !!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand these modes correctly, they are mutually exclusive. First one resizes your layout so it makes some room for the keyboard, another one moves entire layout to the top (w/o resizing). Not sure what do you expect with mixing these modes, but I'm pretty sure they are following `either-or` logic...

Comment: well, I would say nothing :) Anyways, mixing these 2 attributes doesn't make any sense (at least I cannot imagine what to expect from this) :) Can you describe what are you trying to achieve? If you want to remove certain elements from your layout when keyboard is open - you have to do that manually from the code since Android doesn't have any idea what your goal is..

Answer (score 0):

You can't have both modes at the same time as that's nonsensical (should the window resize or pan?).

You can however change the mode at runtime: [`setSoftInputMode`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html).